# Using "value" (or other properties) to get dropdown results in autocomplete widget - jQuery-UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using an array of objects for criteria to search over, using the Autocomplete Widget, and everything works. Every object has properties like:

```
{
   value: "spider",
   label: "Grass Spider",
      ...
}
```

The autocomplete widget seems to only search over the value of `label` though, and ignores `value`. If I search for "spider" the previous example will show up in the search, but if I change `value` to look like this `value: "spider (t1)"` I would like to be able to type "t1", or "(t1)" and have it show up in the search.

Is there a way to have the widget look at `value` OR a way to specify other properties to be used when getting search results in addition to using the `label` property.

Comment: how are you retriving your auto complete data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how you retrieve your data. At the end of the day the autocomplete plugin is going to be looking at the label, but you can pick up a different value from the result set and achieve success that way as well. An example on how to do this is below:

**php**

```
<?php
    // this example will be our source file where all the data comes from
    // and say that we are pulling from a database     
    $term = $_POST['term'];  // term is always the search values post name
    $q = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM Customer WHERE CONCAT(first_name + ' ' + last_name) LIKE ?";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($q);
    $stmt->execute(array("%$term$"));

    // generate a new results arrays
    $results = array();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $results[] = array(
            'label' => $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name'],
            'value' => $row['id']
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

in short what this PHP file is letting you do is take a look at multiple items by concatenating multiple table columns on the select query. You can then store a different value per item that is different from the label, if you do desire, otherwise the label is your default value more than likely, so how do we correct this on the javascript side?

**javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $('#input').autocomplete({
        minLength : 0,
        source : 'myPhpSourceFile.php',
        select : function(event, ui){ 
            // this is where you would grab the value           
            var value = ui.item.value;
            // if you want to use the value for each item instead
            // you can store it in a hidden field
            $('#myhiddenfield').val(value);
            return false; // prevent an event interruption
        }
    });
```

Now for you specific example above that you asked about, the only time that the auto complete will look at the value of the item is when a selection of an item occurs. The only way to have it look at alternate values is going to be how you manipulate the `term` on the server side when gathering your results set. so again going back to the php source file, say there was an added column called `special` then you could do the following:

```
$q = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name, special FROM Customer WHERE
CONCAT(first_name + ' ' + last_name + '('+special'+')') LIKE ?";
```

this result would give you the type of query you want to search against, then on the results set just set the `results` array like so:

```
$results[] = array(
   'label' => $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."(".$row['special'].")",
   'value' => $row['id']
);
```

this will have your results set list show up like `spider man (ti)` as you were asking about above. I'm pretty sure I'm on the same track as what you are asking about but if not please ask more questions or correct where I may be wrong. I hope this helps out!

Comment: This is my first time tackling a project like this, so I'm sure you'll have some critiques of how I'm handling it. Currently I'm just using a local(in the same file as the autocomplete function) array that contains all my data, so the data itself is also javascript. I would like to convert the data to json at some point... I read that it works better/faster for things like this, but currently I'm still wiring up the rest of the structure.

Comment: Your answer helps, I don't have much experience with php but I might give it a go if I can get your method to work. Essentially I want to be able to search by the ```label``` but many of the objects in the database have common property (lets call it T1) so when someone searches for (T1) I would want also objects with that have the T1 property to be displayed also, without having to include T1 in the ```label```

Comment: no critiques here, everyone has to start somewhere, but using my example above, or at least something similar will help you accomplish what you desire. The output from that source file i generate is in JSON notation so it will give you the speed and accuracy you're trying to get. My best advice for you is quickly pick up how sql works, and start experimenting with them. It makes data storage tremendously easier. Also I'm glad that my answer has helped you out. And yes becuse you would be searching for that T1 proper with the query, they would all show with your normal search

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I will do exactly that.